# Getting frequency count while inserting in linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have created two classes for this practice of singly linked list. I wanted to count the frequency of the newly added words while they are being added to the list. But it seems like every time the function runs they only get frequency of 1?
Also the exercise stated that I should add the frequency count in the Node class.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, wordData, freq=1):
        self.next = None
        self.wordData = wordData
        self.freq = freq

class FreqLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None


    def addWord(self, word):
        #appending
        new_node = Node(word)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        current_node = self.head
        while current_node.next:
            current_node = current_node.next
        current_node.next = new_node


        while current_node.next is not None:
            if current_node.wordData == word:
                current_node.freq += 1
                current_node = current_node.next
            current_node.next = current_node.next
        return current_node.freq

    def printList(self):
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node is not None:
            print(current_node.wordData, current_node.freq)
            current_node = current_node.next
```

Comment: Seems like bad design. `freq` should not be a part of Node. IT should be part of `FreqLinkedList`. Because if you have million entries of a word, you'll end up iterating and updating all of them just to add a word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are creating every node with frequency 1. And while you iterate over the linkedlist to update frequency, you simply increment it by 1.
So the earliest entry will have the correct count, while each subsequent entry will have count one less than previous one. Check the below snippet:

```
f = FreqLinkedList()
f.addWord("a")
f.addWord("a")
f.addWord("a")
f.addWord("a")
f.printList()

# output
# a 4
# a 3
# a 2
# a 1
```

**Fix for current design**

Maintain frequency at the linkedlist level. And use it to create new nodes and also to update frequency of existing nodes.

```
from collections import Counter

class FreqLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.freqs = Counter() # maintain freq of all words

    def addWord(self, word):

        # book keeping
        self.freqs.update([word]) # this will prevent splitting into characters
        current_word_freq = self.freqs.get(word)

        # appending
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = Node(word)
            return current_word_freq

        current_node = self.head
        while current_node.next:
            current_node = current_node.next
        current_node.next = Node(word, freq=current_word_freq) # freq != 1

        current_node = self.head
        while current_node.next is not None:
            if current_node.wordData == word:
                current_node.freq = current_word_freq # not freq += 1
            current_node = current_node.next
        return current_word_freq


# Test
f = FreqLinkedList()
f.addWord('a')
f.addWord('a')
f.addWord('a')
f.addWord('b')
f.addWord('b')
f.addWord('c')
f.addWord('d')
f.addWord('d')
f.printList()

# Output
# a 3
# a 3
# a 3
# b 2
# b 2
# c 1
# d 2
# d 2
```

However, this approach is extremely inefficient in general.

**Better design**

You should not have frequency in `Node`. Create a method `get_freq` in linkedlist and use it like `FreqLinkedList().get_freq('a')` :

```
def get_freq(self, word):
        return self.freqs.get(word)
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your comment. Though in the exercise it asks me explicitly to add the frequency to the Node class that's why I have added it there. Is it possible to maintain frequency at the Node level while doing the bookkeeping in linkedlist level? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi! It's me again. I tried running your code but it returns None for most of the words' frequency..

Comment: @mismes_f - check now, I think there was a bug somewhere. I added test cases which work fine. Keep in mind that you need to update your code with my code for it to work `addWord` and `__init__` specifically.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it's working. But when I try adding 'session' for example, the frequency is still None. I think it's accessing to letters, but not strings. I tried adding         self.freqs.update(current_node.wordData) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Whoa! Indeed I missed it! i fixed the code. `Counter('abc') -> {'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1}`. So the change required is `Counter(['abc']) -> {'abc':1}`. thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks so much again. Really appreciate your help. Now it's counting correctly!

Comment: @mismes_f Since you are new to SO, consider marking answers as accepted if they helped solve your question. It's not obligatory though.

Comment: I tried finding the accepting button but couldn't. Now I've found it and accepted yours!  :)